# Reverse proxy of multiple container

Tags: docker, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have 2 API containers (docker) running on port 10000 and 10003. I want to reverse proxy both of them so the API can be called from a single port which is port 80. I am trying to use NGINX to do that and this is my nginx configuration file:

```
worker_processes 1;
 
events { worker_connections 1024; }
 
http {
    server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     container1;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://10.10.10.50:10003;
        }
    }

    server {
      listen        80;
      server_name   container2;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.50:10000;
      }
    }
}
```

I found that it is only working on the container 1 and if there is a request for container 2, it will generate 404 not found warning because the request go to the container 1 instead of container 2.

Comment: Are you trying to load balance or these two are different service containers which you want to access on single port (80)?

Comment: This is not possible. Only one service can listen to a port of the machine. Docker port mapping can be used to map container port to a different port on the machine, but it will allow port 80 to be mapped to only one of the services.

Comment: @LeelaPrasad yes, i want to make these 2 containers accessible from a single port

Comment: ^ That's impossible. You need to choose another port.

Comment: If they are in the same machine, then you can connect api containers and nginx in a docker network and just use one server with two location tags to proxy the requests to respective containers. Ex: location /api1/* > container1 . So any request that you do on say nginx:80/api1/* will be routed to container one. Similarly /api2 will route to container 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution using NGINX. All I need to do is to create a new NGINX container then reconfigure the url of my 2 API container. The configuration file that I wrote looks like this:

```
worker_processes auto;
 
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    upstream container1 {
        server 10.10.10.50:10003;
        }
    upstream container2 {
        server 10.10.10.50:10000;
        }
    server {
        listen 80;

        location /container1/ {
            proxy_pass http://container1/;
        }

        location /container2/ {
            proxy_pass http://container2/;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can make requests for both API containers by using port 80 as it will be re-routed from the port into the designated port (reverse-proxy).